# Как обеспечить запуск .Net exe-файлов из командной строки в linux?

Tags: kernel, mono, linux

Как обеспечить запуск *.Net*-овских *exe*-файлов из командной строки, без необходимости вставки вызова mono перед файлом?

На сайте [*mono*](http://www.mono-project.com/archived/guiderunning_mono_applications/) описан один из способов, с загрузкой модуля *binfmt*.

В [gentoo wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Local.d) - как выполнять команды при запуске, потому что:

```
# sysctl fs.binfmt_misc.register=':CLR:M::MZ::/usr/bin/mono:'
sysctl: setting key "fs.binfmt_misc.register": Invalid argument
```

(здесь спор: [ошибка ли это](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-738809-start-0.html))

посмотреть, что получилось после регистрации можно так:

```
# cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/CLR
enabled
interpreter /usr/bin/mono
flags: 
offset 0
magic 4d5a
```

В ядре главная опция - `CONFIG_BINFMT_MISC`, у меня при значении **=y** не пришлось монтировать файловую систему в `/etc/fstab` (она уже оказалась смонтирована, не знаю кем)

ещё в ядре есть

```
# zgrep BINFMT /proc/config.gz
CONFIG_BINFMT_MISC=y
CONFIG_BINFMT_ELF=y
CONFIG_COMPAT_BINFMT_ELF=y
CONFIG_ARCH_BINFMT_ELF_RANDOMIZE_PIE=y
CONFIG_BINFMT_SCRIPT=y
```

Мне непонятно, как сделать, чтобы файлы запускались без расширения (т.е. чтобы работали одновременно команды, к примеру, `NuGet` и `NuGet.exe`)

Также мне непонятно, о каких ограничениях говорили в статье (на сайте *mono*).

Но, по-моему, был ещё какой-то способ с пересборкой ядра с какими-то (другими?) опциями.

Comment: Хм. Интересный вопрос. Я использую некоторые программы написанные на моно, но при этом не приходится перед запуском писать mono programm.exe. В частности речь идёт о CmisSync. Может, всё таки, это надо программу по особому компилировать, что бы так было?

Comment: для некоторых программ делаются bash-обертки типа /usr/bin/myprog,
там внутри написано mono myprog.exe

Comment: ну и, конечно, ещё есть mkbundle, но мы тут про него разговор не ведем

Answer (score 1):

это решается элементарно при помощи *shell*-«обёртки»:

```
#!/bin/sh
mono /путь/к/программе.exe
```

отредактируйте файл, вписав нужный путь и имя во второй строке, и поместите, например, в `/usr/local/bin` под именем, например, `programma1.exe`:

```
$ sudo cp путь/к/этому/файлу /usr/local/bin/programma1.exe
```

добавьте ему биты исполняемости:

```
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/programma1.exe
```

и запускайте по имени:

```
$ programma1.exe
```

---

имя у такой «обёртки» — произвольное. `programma1.exe` — лишь для примера. можно заменить его на `programma` или что-либо иное подходящее и уникальное.

Comment: этот вариант упомянут в комментарии от 24 мар в 15:38. обёртка - это не решение а костыль, происходящий из разного уровня распространённости знаний.