# Запуск приложения C# на Linux Ubuntu

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, mono

Пишу консольное приложение на C#, очень нужно перенести его на сервер под Linux Ubuntu, но не знаю как. Слышал о проекте под названием Mono, но не понимаю как с ним работать. Если есть туториалы по работе с ним - буду очень рад. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Полагаю, вам не Mono нужен, а .NET Core.

Comment: Да, туториалов в интернете много на любой вкус

Comment: В ubuntu он есть в [пакетах](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin), ставиться в 'один клик' :)

Comment: я так сделал `sudo apt-get install monodevelop` а дальше по ссылке https://4tux.ru/blog/programmiruem_na_c_v_linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в современных версиях дистрибутивов, основанных на дистрибутиве *debian gnu/linux*, для возможности запуска скомпилированного блоба достаточо установки пакета *mono-runtime*:

```
$ sudo apt install mono-runtime
```

после чего можно запускать:

```
$ mono программа.exe
```

---

чтобы можно было запускать непосредственно `программа.exe` без явного указания интерпретатора *mono*, надо либо зарегистрировать в системе [соотетствующий обработчик](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc), либо написать скрипт-обёртку. см. [Как обеспечить запуск .Net exe-файлов из командной строки в linux?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/411157/178576)

Comment: я так сделал `sudo apt-get install monodevelop` а дальше по ссылке https://4tux.ru/blog/programmiruem_na_c_v_linux